# How do you multiply all elements of a table in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

suppose I have a table named dataset(xls table)
I want to Multiply all element by 3.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you mean that you have imported an xls file into Matlab and it is now in a table that you want to perform a mathematical operation on.  Since you can't do that to a table, you need to first convert it to an array, and then you can perform operations on it.
Assuming that all your variables are numeric, you can do that using:

```
table2array(dataset).*3;
```

If you want to save it back in table format, try:

```
dataset{:,:} = dataset{:,:}.*3
```